# How to Configure different .envs in a nuxt.js SPA app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy a new webapp using Nuxt.js
Can you tell me the best practice to configure different .env files ? like prod dev test
I want  to deploy my nuxt app in spa mode and a need different path variables in the different enviroments
thanks in advance

I,ve tried to configure different env in the nuxt.config.js file properties but it didnt work

Comment: what u mean by didnt work? setting env variables in nuxt config will work, but keep in  mind that env variables are bundled at build time, so you need to rebuild when u chagne them

Comment: Thank you , i forgot that the variables are bundled at build time. For sure , thats the reason why i can't change them after generate the spa .